# Python bad request to server

Tags: python, bad-request

I wrote up the following program for adding a HTTP request to Python:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
print('first half done')
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Here is the result after running python.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 00:09:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 308
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Your problem is your carriage returns. Use `\r\n\r\n` (CRLF, CRLF) instead. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3

Comment: @selcuk I have checked your link posted.. but I can't find any paragraph about carriage returns. May I know why \r\n\r\n instead of \n\n？

Comment: It is difficult to explain this as a comment, posted a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the line endings. Instead of `\n`, try using `\r\n`:

```
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

This behaviour is explained in [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3):

> The line terminator for message-header fields is the sequence CRLF. However, we recommend that applications, when parsing such headers, recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore the leading CR.

Obviously the web server (`Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)`) does not follow the recommendation above and only accepts CRLF (`\r\n`) as the line terminator.